# Что означают числа ошибок в выводе badblocks?

Tags: ubuntu, hdd

Что означают эти цифры `139/0/0` ?

> Testing with pattern 0xaa: done
>   Reading and comparing:  99.12% done, 2:05:16 elapsed. (139/0/0 errors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

согласно [этому ответу](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65351/110559) три цифры расшифровываются как:

> num_read_errors, num_write_errors, num_corruption_errors
>
> corruption means comparison with previously written data

или:

> количество_ошибок_чтения, количество_ошибок_записи, количество_ошибок_повреждения
>
> «ошибка повреждения» означает — в сравнении с записанными перед этим данными.

Comment: чекаю винт после того как его уронили в внешнем кармане или как там его =). насколько я понял ничего серьезного =).